# Asp.net and Mssql Database operations time out and rollback

Tags: asp.net, sql, web-config, database-connection, connection-string

I am developing an application that has a big database and it waits a bit long for the result from a few queries. Sometimes, users refreshes interface before the execution is finished.  There are ten users and this scenario occurs so many times.I think scripts do not stop running on sql when the web page is refreshed (becuase performance decrasing so much after a few hours). If so, Can I stop the execution of the script when the page is refreshed. In web.config, will changing `Connect Timeout` attibute stop the execution and rollback operations on database after timeout period is passed? Or Is there any other option in web.config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No `connection timeout` property is meant to set the timeout after which the attempt to **connect** to the SQL server fails. What you need is a `command timeout` for your stored procedure. If you share your code, expect more help.

Comment: I have a lot of stored procedures called. Can I set the default command timeout by web.config? Or should I change the each commands' timeout attribute?

Comment: Commnad timeout needs to be set for every command object. the value of timeout can be read from the config though.